# Connect to MongoDB in secure server

Tags: mongodb, firewall

I have two MongoDB instances on two difference ports of server, and the server's router only allows connection to port 80 and 433. Now I want to connect to those instance from my computer. I'm thinking of using Nginx to proxy connection from subdomains, for example https://example.com/mongodb1, https://example.com/mongodb1, to specific ports of server, but it seems to be impossible since MongoDB only receives connection via TCP, while subdomain config is belong to http/https.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the port on which MongoDB is running https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.port

```
net:
   port: 80
```

However, most likely the HTTP server is already listen to this port, so you cannot use it. Apart from that, the firewall may check the packet content and will block it when it detects non-HTTP traffic.

The proper way would be to open the port (default 27017) in the firewall.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion for using MongoDB GUI (or any kind of database GUIs) with secure server (production server)? Or it is not recommended since the final answer is seem to be opening new port, which should not be done in production?

Comment: Not clear what your problem is. MongoDB is also offered as cloud service, so there are millions of Mongo clients securely connecting over the internet to a MongoDB.

Comment: i'm finding a solution to connect to database server from GUI without opening new ports, in our case is MongoDB. We are using a "closed" Ubuntu server, which is not under our control, and we have to ask for permission to change security configs (opening ports for example). Sometimes we have to apply hot fix/update to database, which is more convenient to do on GUI than on terminal.

Comment: In case you are looking for a tool like phpMyAdmin, this does not exist for MongoDB according to my knowledge.